# $dx(v) = dy(v) = dz(v) = F$ if $v = \mathrm{grad} \ F$?

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I am trying to compute $i_v(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz):= (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)(v,w_1,w_2)$, where $v$ denotes $\mathrm{grad} \  F$.

I tried to rewrite this as
\begin{align*}
i_v(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)(w_1,w_2) &= (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)(v,w_1,w_2) \\
& = dx(v) dy(w_1) dz(w_2)
+ dy(v) dz(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
& + dz(v) dx(w_1) dy(w_2)
 - dx(v) dz(w_1) dy(w_2) \\
& - dy(v) dx(w_1) dz(w_2)
- dz(v) dy(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
\end{align*}

But I am stuck on evaluating $dx(v), dy(v), dz(v)$. The definition of exterior derivative that I am working with is $\mathrm{d} f = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \mathrm{d} x^i$. If I assume $dx(v) = a, \ dy(v) = b, \ dz(v) = c$, then I can further write this as
\begin{align*}
& a dy(w_1) dz(w_2)
+ b dz(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
& + c dx(w_1) dy(w_2)
 - a dz(w_1) dy(w_2) \\
& - b dx(w_1) dz(w_2)
- c dy(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
& = a (dy(w_1) dz(w_2) - dz(w_1) dy(w_2)) \\
& + b (dz(w_1) dx(w_2) - dx(w_1) dz(w_2)) \\
& + c (dx(w_1) dy(w_2) - dy(w_1) dx(w_2)) \\
& = a (dy \wedge dz)(w_1, w_2) + b (dz \wedge dx)(w_1, w_2) + c (dx \wedge dy)(w_1, w_2) \\
& = (a \, dy \wedge dz + b \, dz \wedge dx + c \, dx \wedge dy)(w_1, w_2)
\end{align*}

EDIT: Thanks to the generous hint by Ted Shifrin, it occurs to me that I can write the gradient of $F$ as $v = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\partial_x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\partial_y + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\partial_z$, so $dx(v) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, dy(v) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}, dz(v) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$. Then
\begin{align*}
i_v(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)(w_1,w_2) &= (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)(v,w_1,w_2) \\
& = dx(v) dy(w_1) dz(w_2)
+ dy(v) dz(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
& + dz(v) dx(w_1) dy(w_2)
 - dx(v) dz(w_1) dy(w_2) \\
& - dy(v) dx(w_1) dz(w_2)
- dz(v) dy(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
& = F_x dy(w_1) dz(w_2)
+ F_y dz(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
& + F_z dx(w_1) dy(w_2)
 - F_x dz(w_1) dy(w_2) \\
& - F_y dx(w_1) dz(w_2)
- F_z dy(w_1) dx(w_2) \\
& = F_x (dy(w_1) dz(w_2) - dz(w_1) dy(w_2)) \\
& + F_y (dz(w_1) dx(w_2) - dx(w_1) dz(w_2)) \\
& + F_z (dx(w_1) dy(w_2) - dy(w_1) dx(w_2)) \\
& = F_x (dy \wedge dz)(w_1, w_2) + F_y (dz \wedge dx)(w_1, w_2) + F_z (dx \wedge dy)(w_1, w_2) \\
& = (F_x \, dy \wedge dz + F_y \, dz \wedge dx + F_z \, dx \wedge dy)(w_1, w_2)
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
d(F_x \, dy \wedge dz + F_y \, dz \wedge dx + F_z \, dx \wedge dy) &=
\left(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z^2}\right) dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \\
= (\Delta F) dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \\
\end{align*}

Is what I'm thinking mathematically correct? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You'd better start by getting your formula for the gradient correct,

Comment: That's exactly why I am so confused. The gradient that I know of is of the form $(f_x, f_y, f_z)$, but I think I need something in the form of $a \partial_x + b \partial_y + c \partial_z$ in order to compute $dx(v)$.

Comment: Remember that $\partial_x = (1,0,0)$, etc., when we're working with standard coordinates on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I see. So the gradient of $F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\partial_x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\partial_y + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\partial_z$?

Comment: Yup. Or you can stick with your subscripts for partials.

Comment: I see! I've made changes accordingly. Could you take a look at what I have and see if it's correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You might want, for future reference, to prove that for any $1$-forms $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,$ we have $\iota_v(\alpha\wedge\beta\wedge\gamma) = \alpha(v)\beta\wedge\gamma - \beta(v)\alpha\wedge\gamma + \gamma(v)\alpha\wedge\beta$. Evaluating on vectors and writing out all the permutations is just too painful.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Just a last word. If you're learning differential forms, integration on manifolds, multivariable analysis, ..., you might find some of my YouTube lectures helpful. (However, my definition of wedge product is much more hands-on ... no tensor products and permutations.) They are linked in my profile.

Comment: Sure! I will be sure to check them out! Thanks!